# Complex SQL Query for a custom role provider

Tags: sql, linq

I have an ASP.NET custom role provider with the following tables.

```
[Role] RoleName( PK, nvarchar(100) );

[PermissionGroup] PermissionId( PK, int );PermissionGroupName( nvarchar(256) );

[PermissionGroupHasRole] PermissionGroupId( PK, int );RoleName( PK, nvarchar(100) );

[User] UserId( PK, int ); UserName( nvarchar(100) );

[UserHasPermission] UserId( PK, int ); PermissionGroupId( PK, int );
```

The idea is that roles are assigned to a permission level such as "administrator", "Salesman" etc. and a user can be in a number of groups. e.g. I may be an salesman and an administrator.

My question is what does the SQL or Linq query look like to get a list of the roles for a given user ?
e.g a function such as

```
List<string> GetRolesForUser( int UserId )
{
   SQL Query.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
select PermissionGroupHasRole.RoleName
from PermissionGroupHasRole
where exists
(
  select null 
  from UserHasPermission
  where 
   UserHasPermission.UserId = UserId AND 
   UserHasPermission.PermissionGroupId = PermissionGroupHasRole.PermissionGroupId
)
```